# my phrase_prefix query does not work for numeric values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

my query is pretty simple, it looks like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "something_to_search",
            "type": "phrase_prefix",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "id"
              ...
            ],
            "lenient": true
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

`name` is text value and `id` is numeric value, if I search for "Jo" I will get people who's names starts with "Jo", but if I search for "123" I wont get people who's id's starts with "123", but if I search for the exact id I will get a result.

can someone please tell me how can I get also prefix queries on numeric?

my mappings:

```
{
  "people_db": {
    "mappings": {
      "person": {
        "properties": {
          "address": {
            "properties": {
              "city": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "street": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "streetNumber": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "zipCode": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "country": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you found a solution?